# laravel/php - group by id but still get the every row of data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

this is my table

```
 patient_id  |  vaccine_id
     7              2
     7              3
```

I want it to be displayed like this on my html

patient id: 7, vaccine id: 2,3

I have this query on my controller

```
return App\Notification::join('patients', 'patients.PatientID', '=', 'notifications.patient_id')
                        ->join('parent_accounts', 'parent_accounts.ParentID', '=', 'patients.parent_id')
                        ->join('vaccines', 'vaccines.VaccineID', '=', 'notifications.vaccine_id')
                        ->select('parent_accounts.parent_phonenumber','patients.*','vaccines.vaccine_name')
                        ->where('due_date', $request->due_date)->get();
```

but it's displaying

```
patient id: 7, vaccine id: 2 , patient id: 7, vaccine id: 3
```

I have tried using `groupby('patient_id');`

but it's showing like this `patient id: 7, vaccine id: 2`
it doesnt display the other vaccine id

Comment: use group_concat()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `group_concat(vaccine_id)` with `groupby('patient_id')` to get the desired format like:

```
->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(vaccine_id)')
```

Comment: Sounds great !!